# Xubuntu 16 Conky breaks notifications and menus

Tags: xfce, menu, conky

I am running into an interesting problem that I haven't seen before. Without Conky running, my notification bar works fine. But as soon as I start Conky and click on any icons like sound, or dropbox, the menu doesn't appear. I thought it was a problem with my XFCE settings. I am running 4 monitors in a 2x2 pattern, main monitor is bottom left, I have my task bar on the bottom of that screen, and conky on the right side of that monitor. 
Additionally, it also breaks the menus on programs like Notepadqq, the file menus at the top of the window don't show up right, but right click menus work fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. Changed `own_window_type` from `panel` to `dock`